# Chrome + Office 365 : Can't I open my emails in Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, email, microsoft-outlook

For the last couple of days I haven't been able to open my emails in Chrome on my PC.

I can see incoming emails, but when I click them, they won't show their content.

I can view my email on my laptop, phone(webapp), phone(bluemail app).

I tried to fix it by clearing cache and cookie (even restarting windows), but that doesn't help either. But this is the strangest thing, I open a new window by using "new Incognito window" feature, login into my 365 mail account, and voila everything worked like a charm.

Any idea? Thanks for reading.

Chrome version : 65.0.3325.181（Official Build） (32 bit)

Comment: Have you tried a different user profile, this is different then clearing your cache or cookies, don’t sync your google account to this new user profile

Comment: @Ramhound now you mention, I recall that this happened when I started syncing my Goolgle account on this PC's chrome.

Comment: @Ramhound so now we know that causes this, is there any workaround ? I don't want to un-sync my Google account :(

Comment: Are you sure it isn’t an extension that is turned off in incognito mode?

Comment: @Appleoddity Wonderful, it was Adblock that causes the problem. By turning off Adblock on outlook site, the problem is gone. Thanks alot. You mind adding your comment as answer so I can mark it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chrome disables extensions by default in Incognito mode. Check to see if any extensions are causing the issue.

UPDATE: OP says AdBlock was causing the issue. Whitelisting the Outlook site took care of the issue.